IsTemporal has missing DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK in EF Core 8 migration script for SQL Server
I use EF Core 8 with SQL Server 2022. I have an entity that is configured to use history table with a call to IsTemporal().
Generated migration script has this line:
) WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [test_schema].[foo_history]));

But I would like to have a DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK switch on, as I can see that on some of the materials on the internet.
Expected:
) WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [test_schema].[foo_history], DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON));

Is this switch missing because of EF Core 8 changes or because of the database version?
Would it be possible to add it without using raw SQL in the migration code?

Looks that the mentioned check is not needed on new tables.
According to the documentation (here):

When an existing history table is specified when enabling
SYSTEM_VERSIONING, a data consistency check is performed across both
the current and the history table. It can be skipped if you specify
DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = OFF as an extra parameter.
We highly recommend that you set SYSTEM_VERSIONING with
DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON, to enforce data consistency checks on
existing data.

